# Change URL Rewrite Rule in Web.Config from Code C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to modify rewrite rule from C# code. Url Rewrite rule is resides in web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="partners">
          <match url="^partners$" />
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  url="partners.aspx" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="news">
          <match url="^news$" />
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  url="news.aspx" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="projects">
          <match url="^projects$" />
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  url="projects.aspx" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I want to change for ex. `<rule name="partners"> <match url="^partners$" />` to `<rule name="partners"> <match url="^friendship/partners$" />`,

how can I find node rule and update match url to "new one" where name = "partners";?

this is my idea for dynamic url rewriting. thanks for any other ways if you have.

Comment: You want to modify those rules from within the same web application or from within some other application? Were you aware that if you modify web.config the application will recycle?

Comment: Within the same application...
you say that it's impossible? thanks

Comment: Am I able to configure Web.Config at any page_event? ex. Page_Init()?

Comment: Yes, but this will kill your application.

Comment: A better solution would be to change your application so that it can accept variable URL's and e.g. use [ASP.NET URL routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) to pass all parameters to your application. Modifying web.config has a lot drawbacks and you might eventually run into scaling issues if you have many rewrites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS URL dynamic rewriting ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812311/iis-url-dynamic-rewriting-ways)

Answer (score 1):

I change value for connectionString in my web.config website with this code :

May be this example can help you (just change the value `connectionString` by `system.webServer` and `add` by `rules` etc..
Please tell me if it works for you

```cs
XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load("../myPath/web.config");
foreach (XmlNode node in myXmlDocument["configuration"]["connectionStrings"])
{
    if (node.Name == "add")
    {
        if (node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value == "SCI2ConnectionString")
        {
            node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("connectionString").Value = "new value";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a reasonable way as the website will be down every time you re-save your web.config file

Comment: yes this will mean to kill your application website . it will restart the web site every change web.config sorry .i will check if we have another solutions ;-)

Comment: consider this solution. another question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812311/iis-url-dynamic-rewriting-ways

Comment: waouh ok perfect ! Thank you for that ;-)  I agree it's a good solution with a good article

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:-** download urlrewrite2.exe [Here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

**Step 2:-**  write you logic in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <providers>
      <provider name="FileMap" type="FileMapProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f">
        <settings>
          <add key="FilePath" value="D:\j\branches\JuzBuzz\App_Data\rewriteurl.txt" />
          <add key="IgnoreCase" value="1" />
          <add key="Separator" value="," />
        </settings>
      </provider>
    </providers>
    <rules>
      <rule name="FileMapProviderTest" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{FileMap:{R:1}}" pattern="(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**step 3:-** Put you .txt file in App_Code folder or another place for which you have given the address in web.config , txt file will have data  like

**technology,expert/search-expert.aspx?CatId=1

counselling-personal-growth,expert/search-expert.aspx?CatId=2**  etc**

Comment: hello , can you be more clear for step 3. any exemples

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll available to help you out, but it requires administrator permissions to execute,

https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration

It is quite suitable for a WinForms application (such as IIS Manager) to control an IIS server, but can also be used in other types of applications.

I do have a personal project that is a custom MWA implementation that works for some non-administrator cases. If you are interested in it, let me know.