# IIS URL dynamic rewriting ways

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, dynamic, url-rewriting

What are the ways of **dynamic url rewriting** in IIS, asp.net web page.
I know one of them is to add rules into config dynamically, but that has some disadvantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use custom rewrite providers with the IIS Url Rewrite Module. There is a good article on the subject [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/803/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module/).

The DbProvider might be the most useful to you if you want dynamic rewrite rules.

Comment: I've read this one, installed url-rewriter runtime but there are no providers found. It's empty. Any idea?

P.S. I have had rewriter module before and now installed for "runtime" again.

Comment: @levanlevi - the installer puts the providers into the GAC (they must be installed there for IIS to pick them up), it might be worth checking that they are indeed there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Url Rewriting using IIS Url Rewriting Module

[URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite)

1. Asp.Net Routing

[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

1. Urlrewriting.Net

[UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewrite](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html)

I would recommend using ASP.Net Routing.