# IIS 7 rewrite module, is it possible to programatically define the rewriting rules rather than manage them in the Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewrite-module

I'm working on a bespoke CMS system for which each of our customers have their own domain name through which they access our their content on our system.  For this we are using the IIS rewrite module to ensure that each domain points to the content which each customer owns.

An example of our rewrite rule is as follows,

```
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRuleCustomerX" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?customerx.com" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/Public/([A-Z][a-z].+)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/combres.axd/([A-Z][a-z].+)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/Community/([1-9][0-9])/([A-Z][a-z].+)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/fbchannel.ashx" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/Community/10/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
```

What I would like to do is to dynamically and programatically define these rules via code in my ASP MVC project rather than rely on the web.config which requires someone go in and tinker with the production server each time we need to set up a new customer.

I don't wan't to dynamically modify the web.config, I would prefer to remove the responsibility of managing these rules from the web.config all together.

Is it possible to dynamically declare these rules in code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812311/iis-url-dynamic-rewriting-ways

Comment: @lat3ncy those solutions still require the web.config to be modified for new rules to be added.

Comment: It will only require one rule to be setup during deployment that passes all traffic to the rewrite provider, ie. Match URL .*

Answer (score 0):

What your looking to do could be easily implemented in a custom rewrite provider. We have had great success using them for large content migration projects where simple pattern based rewriting was not an option.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Whenever possible we prefer to avoid link-only answer, and prefer if you quoted part of and/or summarized the content from the link; if the link ever moves or dies this answer will become less useful.

Comment: A very good point Michael, I will expand the post shortly. It does make me wonder if SO would benefit from external link handling and redirection to their own or an existing Internet Archive project. Off to meta... (I'm learning slowly)