# Map MVC path to root .cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I am developing a single page application using MVC+ServiceStack. What I want to do is implement an "admin" site that uses a different set of resources and theme from the main site. (I guess it's a two page application)

What I am trying to do is use the index.cshtml for the main site, this is already done. The second thing I wanted to do was have an admin.cshtml file in the root folder, and map the site path "~/admin.cshtml" to it.

Can this be done?

Constraints:

- None of the cshtml pages have controllers
- Both reside in the root folder
- The mapped path should not contain a file extension, e.g. it should be http://mysite.com/admin, not http://mysite.com/admin.cshtml

Thanks

Comment: Can you not create a controller (e.g. homecontroller) with a view name of `admin` and then create a static route in the route table? Would this be an option for you or am I missing something?

Comment: It's a strange constraint, but the site may switch away from MVC. That's why I'm trying to stay away from a controller. What you are suggesting is a plan B.

Comment: Plan B: Make it straight ASP.NET, register a route to ignore `/admin` and don't register a default route.  And then use ASP.NET url rewriting, ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752279/change-url-rewrite-rule-in-web-config-from-code-c-sharp specific for those two main routes (`/` and `/admin`).

Comment: Interesting choice, but still the plan B, and requires IIS customization, which I might not be able to do.

Comment: IIS customization?  You can do this with just web.config and server-side code, no?  What version of IIS is this running on?

Comment: I am not doing the deployment... you need to have the IIS URL Rewrite Module installed, right?

Comment: Fair enough, but that's just an example.  There are simple .NET components that can be installed, such as http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html Though I still think your best bet is to create a controller that returns the "Views." (`return View("~/admin.cshtml");` might work, so you can keep your file in the root).  If you move off of MVC, go with an alternative such as a URL rewriting component (that can be installed as a part of the website and not as an IIS module).