# How to create a redirect in a web.config file for a specific file type?

Tags: iis, web-config, http-redirect

I have a large podcast site with several thousand mp3 files.  I am running Wordpress on Windows Azure.  I recently moved servers and changed url structure.

In the past all of the mp3 files were referenced by (rough example, there are several thousand files)

The were located at 
http://www.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname/filename.mp3 -

they are now located at 
http://downloadtracker.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname/filename.mp3

The only difference is the subdomain changing from "www" to "downloadtracker"

I have fixed all internal links manually - but there are numerous inbound links I can't control.  What I would like to do is to create a rule in the web.config that sniffs for a request for an mp3 file and redirects the request to the new subdomain.  I would like it to automatically redirect for every mp3 file (and I would not have to manually code every mp3 path)

I have seen no way to sniff and redirect based on file type in the web.config.  Is that even possible?

Comment: This should neither be related to wordpress nor azure (remove tags?). Do you mean http://downloadtracker.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname/filename.mp3 for the target URI? Did you look at IIS rewrite rules?

Comment: It is a wordpress site that is running on Azure - I do want downloadtracker.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname/filename.mp3 to be where the user is redirected.

Comment: I have not looked at IIW rewrite rules, just the web.config ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rewrite rule redirects all requests to MP3 files with the path pattern you described to your new host.

```xml
<rule name="redirect MP3s" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^podcasts/.*/.*.mp3$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="downloadtracker.domain.com" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://downloadtracker.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Note that the condition (that checks if the host is not already where we are going to redirect to) prevents redirect loops in case both `www.domain.com` and `downloadtracker.domain.com` are hosted on the same IIS instance. If this is not the case the condition can be omitted.

Also be aware that you might want to change the `redirectType` from `Permanent` (which causes a [301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)) to `Found` (which causes a [301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)) if the measure is only temporary and you do not want clients to remember the new location.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a VM loaded to test this but a rewrite rule similar to below should work. The URL's might need to be relative instead of absolute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rule Name" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://www.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname/filename.mp3" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://downloadtracker.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname.mp3" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Would that work for every mp3 file?  I am trying to do the redirect for every request for an mp3 file (there are several thousand).

Comment: for every mp3 file you would need to do <match url="*.mp3"

Comment: How can I both match the mp3 and also redirect it to the same path, but with a different domain name?

Comment: It is going to involve something like {c:0} in the action url to get the parameters from the incoming url. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22146028/540339 it may provide a way for you to define the rules.

Comment: I have not seen that answer - I spent most of yesterday trying to find the right combination of {R0},{C1} values.  It is an odd gap for MS to have.

Answer (score 0):

If IIS is hard to configure for that redirection, you could eventually consider using a reverse proxy, for example an apache server. Apache is good at reverse proxying, ie transparently forwarding all traffic sent to an URL to another one.

Extract from apache 2.4 doc on module `mod_proxy`, directive `ProxyPass`:

```
Suppose the local server has address http://example.com/; then

<Location /mirror/foo/>
    ProxyPass http://backend.example.com/
</Location>

will cause a local request for http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar to be internally converted into a proxy request to http://backend.example.com/bar.
```

So, you simply have to install an Apache server listening on `www.domain.com`. The magic directive will then be :

```
<Location /podcasts/podcastname/>
    ProxyPass http://downloadtracker.domain.com/podcasts/podcastname/
</Location>
```

It is current on large datacenters to have reverse proxies for security reasons, load balancing, ...

EDIT :
I must admit all this makes sense only if you allready have (or plan to have) such reverse proxies in your production environment. If you use other reverse proxies such as `nginx` it should also be easy. Of course I you have no reverse proxies and do not need to, it is better to stick to an IIS solution. But if you have a lot of traffic or strong security concerns, maybe it would be useful.